# Use method to get value in asp:repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When I loop through my data in c# I have to use the below to get the value:

```
foreach (var item in documentQuery)
{
   string value = item.getproperty("title");
  //value = "hello world"
}
```

But if I want to bind the results to an asp:repeater in an ASPX page how would I call this same getproperty method in the ItemTemplate? Because if I just go <%# Eval("title") %> it gives an error...

Answer (score 0):

`Eval()` is a shortcut to simplify binding.  To do something more complex, you won't be able to use it.

I think you need to do something like:

```
<%# Container.DataItem.getproperty("title")) %>
```

Or you might have to cast Container.DataItem to your specific type of item:

```
<%# (Container.DataItem as XXXXXXX).getproperty("title")) %>
```

where `XXXXXXX` is whatever the type your item is.

Comment: <%# (Container.DataItem as XXXXXXX).getproperty("title")) %>
 this works! however since im going to be using a lot of values im thinking of trying to do something cleaner. What if I used ondatabound and used getproperty in codebehind to bind to a asp:literal or would that be considered bad practice?

Comment: Might work, but what I would do is use LINQ to select the result of documentQuery into an anonymous type and just bind to that, so something like:  repeater.DataSource = documentQuery.Select(x => new { title = x.getproperty("title") });  if you do it that way, then your original problem goes away and you can just do Eval("title") like you tried to originally and it should work.